# Changed the Server's hostname and home page loads empty, but central administration loads fine

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 R2. We had to change the server's hostname and the Sharepoint 80 homepage loaded completely empty, but the Central Administration loaded fine. We changed the name back and everything was normal.

Is there an aditional process to change the server's host name without affecting Sharepoint 80 pages?

Comment: when you change the host name, did you update the AAM settings? pointing the new host name if you are using server name and port number

Comment: We changed the Alternate Access Mappings to reflect the name change, but did the same.

Comment: what happen, if you browse from IIS( right click on the IIS site, click browse)?